# apt-get doesn't work on Raspbian 3.6.11+

Tags: raspberry-pi, apt-get, raspbian

When I try to do an apt-get (install, update or upgrade no matter) my Raspberry does nothing.

I checked my /etc/apt/sources.list and updated it with the mirrors on Raspbian.org.

Is someone knows what's happenning ?

Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: What do you mean by "it does nothing" ? What appears on the screen ?

Comment: Hello, thanks for you response. Here what appears on the screen: pi@raspberry ~$: sudo apt-get install and when I execute the command I get pi@raspberry ~$:

Comment: Can I suggest you to look here and try their procedures ? :)
http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=49421&p=389198

Comment: Thanks :) The command sudo apt-get --config give me no output too. It seems to be a configuration problem

Comment: Have you tried Davespice's solution ?
    sudo -s
    rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/lock
    cd /var/lib/dpkg
    mv status status-bad
    cp status-old status
    exit
    sudo apt-get update

Comment: Yes I tried it but no output :(